# jQuery focus blur pass parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I can't seem to access the variable `defaultValue` down in my `.blur()` function. I've tried various stuff but with no luck. So far I only get an empty object. What's wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#nameInput, #emailInput, #webInput').focus(function(){      
        var defaultValue = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery(this).val("");
    })
    .blur(function(defaultValue){   
         if(jQuery(this).val() == ""){
             jQuery(this).val(defaultValue);
         }
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 9):

Looks like the question is about the passing data into the .blur or .focus event.
per jQuery API - http://api.jquery.com/blur/

```
blur( [eventData ], handler(eventObject) )
```

So if you want to pass data -  you can send a parameter to event - which will appear as data in event object.

see this fiddle for more info

http://jsfiddle.net/dekajp/CgP2X/1/

```
var p = {
    mydata:'my data'
};

/* p could be element or whatever */
$("#tb2").blur(p,function (e){
    alert('data :'+e.data.mydata);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Because your code is wrong :-) you define var inside function (`var defaultValue`) which is then immediately wiped out.

There are two solutions: define your var as a global var before you bind blur event, or store it in the data of object liket his (which I recommend):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nameInput, #emailInput, #webInput').focus(function(){      
        $(this).val("").data('defaultValue',jQuery(this).val());
    }).blur(function(defaultValue){   
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).val($(this).data('defaultValue'));
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you don't understand the basics of JavaScript.

First of all variables in JS are localized to function's scope, so you can't declare variable with `var` in one function and access it in other function

Second, you can't pass anything to DOM-event handler, except event-object, this is defined by the DOM specification, sometimes you can use `event data` parameter to the `blur` jQuery method.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var defaultValue;
    jQuery("#nameInput, #emailInput, #webInput").focus(function(){      
        defaultValue = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery(this).val("");
    })
    .blur(function(){   
        if(jQuery(this).val() == ""){
            jQuery(this).val(defaultValue);
        }
     }); 

 });
```

First of all, you need to distinguish `blur` method (function) and `handler` (function) which is the argument to the `blur`. You was trying to pass the `defaultValue` exactly to handler, but that can't be done. Inside handler the `defaultValue` would be equal `eventObject`, so you can do smth like `console.log(defaultValue.timeStamp)` and you'll see smth like `123482359734536`

In your approach you can't even use `event.data` argument to the `blur` cause it will be set at the time of `blur`'s call (attaching handler). You need to declare a `var` outside of the both handlers, so it will be visible to both of them

You may consider to read some comprehensive book on JS.

I read "Professional JaveScript For Webdevelopers" by Nicolas Zakas. There is a new edition

Comment: I was already aware that a variable defined inside the function were localized to that specific function. I was trying to pass the variable as parameter to the blur function but don't know how to exactly. Doing it this way rather than globalizing the variable seemed like the more elegant solution.